# How to rotate every second page in a pdf?

Tags: pdftex, rotating

I have a pdf and need to have each second page turned upside down, so that I can print it twosided.
I found [pdfpages rotate odd pages 180º](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244107/pdfpages-rotate-odd-pages-180%C2%BA)
and changing

```
 \foreach \p in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
  \ifnumodd{\p}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p,angle=180]{\jobname-step1}}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p]{\jobname-step1}}%
}
```

to

```
 \foreach \p in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
  \ifnumodd{\p}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p,angle=180]{\jobname-step1}}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p+1]{\jobname-step1}}%
}
```

(amongst other changes) would do the job I think. But adding the `\p+1` gives an error. I tried it with the package calc, but without any luck.

Comment: Many printer drivers can be configured to do this for you automatically (no LaTeX required).

Comment: please, why are you  doing this (`\p+1`) in the first place?

Comment: It's also possible to do this outside LaTeX. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/rotate-pdf-pages-90-degrees-for-even-pages-and-90-degrees-for-odd-pages (and the linked question from that) has some solutions. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508119/rotate-odd-pages-20deg-even-20deg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437123/custom-angle-page-rotation?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 2):

After some long hours I got the following to do the job:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath,pdfpages}

\def\originalfile{backlog-grooming.pdf}

\begin{document}

\pdfximage{\originalfile}%
\foreach \p in {1,3,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
   \pgfmathparse{int(\p+1)}%
   {\includepdf[pages=\p]{\originalfile}}%
   {\includepdf[pages=\pgfmathresult,angle=180]{\originalfile}}%
}


\end{document}
```

In the file backlog-grooming.pdf every second page is turned upside down.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\foreach \p in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
  \ifnumodd{\p}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p]{\jobname-step1}}%
    {\includepdf[pages=\p,angle=180]{\jobname-step1}}%
}
```