# Custom angle page rotation

Tags: rotating, page

I know it is possible to rotate figures, tables, tikzpictures. Also, I know that it is possible to rotate an entire page by 90 debrees (portrait/landscape), but is it possible to rotate an entire page with custom angle, for example using syntax that inputs which page should be rotated as well as the angle, as `\rotatepage{pagenumber = 2}{angle = 20}`?

So I would like to have an entire page rotated including the page number as well. But only what is contained on the page should be rotated. Everything that has been broken to the next page should not be rotated.

Comment: Of course you can always do some `\rotatebox{..}{\begin{minipage}{...} ... \end{minipage}` but I am not sure that this looks nice.

Comment: @marmot thanks for the suggestion! I would like to have an entire page rotated including the page number as well. But only what is contained on the page should be rotated. Everything that has been broken to the next page should not be rotated

Comment: You can use a TikZ-`node` in such a way that it represents the content of the page. The rotation can be done via an `option` for the `node` (e.g. `\node[rotate=ANGLE]` or more specific rotation …). For the page break-argument (as you mentioned in your question) there must be written a few lines on that, but it is definitely possible.

Comment: @NikolaDjordjevic, thanks for the suggestions! I edited my question. Do you have a proposal?

Comment: Maybe it would work like this:
`pdfLaTeX` gives each page a number (which can optionally be hidden). That is, the "page information" confers and stores. One would have to start there and write a kind of `switch-case` instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rotate and displace the shipout box. But you can't rotate the "pdf background", the pdf reference allows only multiples of 90.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,atbegshi}
\begin{document}
\lipsum 
\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{%
 \rotatebox{35}{\hspace{-4cm}\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}% 
}}%

\lipsum      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Random orientation of every page could be done like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,atbegshi,xfp}
\begin{document}

\AtBeginShipout{%
\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{%
 \rotatebox[origin=c]{\fpeval{randint(360)}}{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}% hspace to get the box more left
}}%
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ultike Fischer, thanks! :D is it possible to give every page a random rotation automatically?

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: what does it use as turning point (pivot)?

Comment: Check the graphics documentation.

Comment: you used origin = c, but rotation doesn't seem to be rotated around the center?

Comment: how can I make it rotate between range of two angles?

Comment: it does not work in Xelatex

Comment: No xetex is missing the necessary primitive for random numbers. You will have to implement some pseudo random function.

Comment: I tried 0.2*rand but it does not work. Do you know how to generate random number between range in Xelatex?