# Rotate odd pages 20deg, even -20deg

Tags: rotating

I have a 1000 page pdf that I'm trying to rotate the pages on. I can do this in InDesign but it would take forever, so I'm looking into tex.

Can this be done easily and how would I go about it?

I'm on a mac if it makes any difference and a total novice to tex. I have installed texbasic and TexWorks.

I came across this in my search:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages={-},angle=30]{main}
\end{document}
```

I edited "30" to "20" to get the angle then I edited "main" to the document name of my pdf and it worked!

However it is exporting all the pages at US Letter size and scaling my artwork up to suit. I need it not to scale my artwork.

Comment: welcome to TEXSE. What have you tried so-far? The questions in this site must revolve around a certain specific problem. Nevertheless, the short answer is yes and you can look into the package `pdfpages` and `graphics`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I haven't tried anything as I'm not even sure how to use it in TexWorks. Opening the pdf seems to only allow me to view it. I came across this:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages={-},angle=30]{main}
\end{document}

Comment: what do you mean by only allow you to view it? you can basically read the pdfpages via your script and rotate it directly.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437160/2388

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom angle page rotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437123/custom-angle-page-rotation)

Comment: The linked question is indeed very related but it does not address how to apply different amounts of rotation for odd and even pages - so I voted to leave open.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573189/rotating-pdfs-less-than-90-degrees which has a Perl answer, I didn't test if it works but it would be trivial to alternate the amount of rotation between pages using this method.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/rotate-pdf-file-less-than-90-degree, there using `convert` is mentioned, which has the disadvantage of rasterizing the image - but if you want to rotate 20 degrees then it is probably a scan of some sort, so it is most likely already rasterized (therefore the disadvantage does not apply).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages):

> By default pages are scaled automatically. This can be suppressed with the `noautoscale` option. In combination with the scale option (from [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) the user has full control over the scaling process. Either `true` or `false` (or no value, which is equivalent to `true`). (Default: `noautoscale=false`)

So,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages={-},angle=20,noautoscale]{main}
\end{document}
```

If you want opposite angles for odd and even, you can loop through the pages and include odd/even pages using a condition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={-},angle=\ifodd\value{page} 20\else -20\fi,noautoscale]{main}

\end{document}
```

Or, perhaps a little more verbose:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=1+1}{1000}{%
  \ifodd\i % \i is odd
    \includepdf[pages=\i,angle=20,noautoscale]{main}%
  \else % \i is even
    \includepdf[pages=\i,angle=-20,noautoscale]{main}%
  \fi
}

\end{document}
```