# How to achieve layout for single sheet folded book

Tags: book-design

I would like to use TeX (or ConTeXt) to take my text and images in a source doc and output a PDF suitable folding a [single sheet book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Zine_Making/Putting_pages_together#An_8-sided_zine_from_1_sheet_with_1_cut) of eight pages from a tabloid piece of paper. The layout is illustrated below has eight 3.75x5in text and image blocks separated by 1/2" margins in between blocks and 1/4" margins on the outside:

[image: 8 page single sheet book layout]

Pages 2-7 are rotated 180 degrees from 1 and 8.

I basically have no idea where to start!

Comment: Have a look at the `pdfpages` package.

Comment: Would I be creating the PDF pages separately and then using pdfpages on a master document to pull them in and arrange them? I'm understanding the function of that package is to include PDF files into a LaTeX doc? Sorry if I'm being obtuse.

Comment: Yes, one LaTeX run would create a document in normal order, then pdfpages would reorder them and put them 4 to a page.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244107/pdfpages-rotate-odd-pages-180%c2%ba?s=1|69.6926 (somewhat related).

Comment: Or, I assume, 8 to a page as in this case. I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: not exactly specific to this layout, but related.  an episode in peter wilson's "clisterings" column in tugboat describes several different layouts and how to achieve them: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf .

Comment: Thank you! Figure 5 in that document is essentially the same layout.