# How to have some pages rotated with pdfpages

Tags: rotating, pdfpages

I'm trying to make a zine (8 page folded booklet) using LaTeX that takes in an 8 page pdf and arranges the pages properly to print, but have an issue where I have to also have a flipped pdf inputted instead of it just reading from one pdf. Is there any way to easily have the pages be rotated, or to automatically generate the flipped pdf and put it in?

Here's what I have:

```
\batchmode
\documentclass[letter,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
                    help lines/.append style={line width=0.05pt,
                                              color=grey!25}]
  \draw [help lines, dashed,ystep=4.25in,xstep=2.75in] (0,0) grid(28,22);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge[nup=4x2, landscape=false,scale=1,
offset=0cm 0cm,delta=0cm 0cm,trim=0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,clip]{pdf_sample_flip.pdf,5,4,3,2,pdf_sample.pdf,6,7,8,1}

\end{document}
```

The code works completely fine as is, but it'd be really convenient to not have to put in a flipped pdf as well.

Comment: I guess your solution is the best you can get. Unfortunately you cannot rotate individual pages with pdfpages.

Comment: Pdfpages does a good job with multiple pages, but trying to treat one page differently, not so much.  OTOH, you can always use `\includegraphics` to do them one at a time.  BTW, a lot of the parameters (e.g. `offset=0cm 0cm`) do nothing.

Comment: Perhaps with this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452912/selectively-rotate-pages-when-using-pdfpages-includepdf/452927#452927